# Adding a New Feature

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

My question is pretty straightforward and the task behind is related to binary classification. To add a new feature, do i  first do `train_test_split` then add a new feature to each split (train and test)? Or should i just add the new feature to the whole dataset initially then proceed to `train_test_split`?

Originally, I have six features. This new feature that I want to add is based on the consequence of calculating the mean square displacement (MSD) between data points for let's say, feature 1.

I saw some posts in here that feature selection (which ones to keep or even normalization) should be done after `train_test_split` to eliminate room for bias, but I am not sure about the process on **adding** a new feature.

Comment: If you’re deriving the new feature from the outcome, I think that completely changes the situation and warrants elaboration in an edit to the original question. For instance, how do you create that feature when it comes time to make predictions for genuinely new data where you truly do not know the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is getting at **leakage** — in this case, allowing information to 'leak' from the training set into the testing set.

If your feature is just computed directly from other features, one record (row) at a time, with no influence from statistics computed over the whole dataset, then it doesn't matter if you create the feature before or after splitting because you are maintaining the assumption of independence between the records.

On the other hand, if you use statistics from the entire dataset, then you must do all your training and fitting — including parameterizing new features etc — on the training set only. For example, if you are standardizing the data then the mean and variance come from `X_train` only.

Hopefully, armed with the intuition that you can't mix information from the training set into data that ends up in the validation or testing sets, you can make smart decisions about any feature engineering steps you are considering.

(FWIW, it sounds like you are in the latter situation and should therefore split first.)